# Manipulando dinamicamente o DOM com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

O sistema que estou trabalhando atualmente exige bastante AJAX e manipulação DOM, logo comecei a aprender (há não muito tempo), jQuery.

Na *feature* que estou desenvolvendo atualmente , existe um plugin jQuery chamado **multi-select**, que tem como objetivo selecionar alguns destinos para posteriormente salva-los.

O fluxo é o seguinte:

1. O usuário seleciona as opções dentro do meu "multi-select";
2. Em seguida o mesmo pressiona o botão "Filtrar";
3. Logo,  alguns componentes são adicionados no DOM dentro de um div com `id="divId"`.

Abaixo uma imagem que talvez ajude a ilustrar o problema:

[image]

Até agora o que eu consegui de fato fazer é adicionar os componentes via jQuery, como mostrado abaixo:

```
$('#show-destination').click(function () {

   $('#divId').prepend('<h5 id="destination-title">Nova York <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-fechar"><span class="entypo-cancel-squared"></span></a></h5>');

   $('#destination-title').after('<div id="div-departure" class="box03"></div>');
   $('#div-departure').append('<div id="div-input-departure" class="input-group "></div');
   $('#div-input-departure').append('<span id="span-departure" class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>');
   $('#span-departure').after('<input id="input-departure" type="text" class="form-control" id="data4" placeholder="Data de Ida">');

   $('#div-departure').after('<div id="div-arrive" class="box03"></div>');
   $('#div-arrive').append('<div id="div-input-arrive" class="input-group "></div');
   $('#div-input-arrive').append('<span id="span-arrive" class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>');
   $('#span-arrive').after('<input id="input-arrive" type="text" class="form-control" id="data4" placeholder="Data de Volta">');

});
```

O problema na realidade é adicionar tais componentes via jQuery de forma dinâmica. Digo, quando o usuário selecionar os destinos no plugin  e clicar em "Filtrar" o mesmo deve popular a "Div" na lateral com o nome dos destinos  e realizar uma chamada AJAX para popular posteriormente uma lista.

---

**EDIÇÃO**

Quando seleciono algum registro no meu componente de multi-select o html renderizado é:

```
<div class="ms-selection">
   <ul class="ms-list" tabindex="-1">
      <li class="ms-elem-selection" id="49-selection" style="display: none;"><span>Roma</span></li>
      <li class="ms-elem-selection ms-selected" id="50-selection" style=""><span>Paris</span></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Como podemos reparar o `ms-selected` no destino **paris** foi selecionado.

A questão é que quero obter todos esses registros selecionados e adicionar elementos no DOM (Incluindo esses nomes).

Mais ou menos como isso:

```
   // pesquisa de todos os elementos ‘div’ na página 
   $('div.ms-selection > ul').each(function (i) {
       //Obtenho todos os registros e trabaho com eles
   });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dentro do `<ul>`, os `<li>` são diferenciados pela classe `ms-selected`, e a função [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) vai determinar isso. Aqui, estou fazendo um loop com:

```
$('.ms-selection ul.ms-list li').each(function() {});
```

E conferindo se o li tem a classe "selecionada", a partir daí, popular o `#divId`.

```js
$('#show-destination').click(function() {
  $('.ms-selection ul.ms-list li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('ms-selected')) {
      $('#divId').prepend('<h5>' + $(this).text() + '</h5>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ms-selection">
  <ul class="ms-list" tabindex="-1">
    <li class="ms-elem-selection" id="49-selection" style="display: none;"><span>Roma</span>
    </li>
    <li class="ms-elem-selection ms-selected" id="50-selection" style=""><span>Paris</span>
    </li>
    <li class="ms-elem-selection ms-selected" id="51-selection" style=""><span>Madrid</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br />
<div id="divId">Items selecionados</div>
<br />
<button id="show-destination">show</button>
```